# How to hide the shadow of toolbar in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I have created a toolbar in my **Android App**. Now what I want is to hide the **shadow** that is being shown as in the picture below
[image]

and here is my **code** for it
*app_bar_home.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="zitat.entwicklers.org.HomeActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_home" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_share" /></android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just add `app:elevation="0dp"` in `AppBarLayout`.

Comment: How to do it for specific activity?

Answer (score 1):

Add 

`if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);`

after `setContentView()` in your activity